# How we can add new button for each row in a Dashlet

Tags: sugarcrm

Can anyone give me some tips on adding a custom button for each row in a Dashlet. I want to add this button before the Edit and Display buttons which are present there by default.

Any help wil be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the array $dashletData['dashletName']['columns'] in the file dashletName.data.php, add a column for the button

```
<?php
...
'test' => array(
  'width'   => '10', 
  'label'   => 'LBL_TEST',
  'default' => true
),
...
?>
```

In the file dashletName.php, you need a method process()

```
<?php
...
function process($lvsParams = array()) {
  parent::process($lvsParams);

  // code to add a button in each row
  foreach($this->lvs->data['data'] as $rowNum => $row) {
    $this->lvs->data['data'][$rowNum]['TEST'] = '<input type="button" name="test" value="test" onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML = \'\';" />';
  }
}
...
?>
```